# How to allocate a remote pty using Net::SSH::Connection::Channel#request_pty

Tags: ruby, pty, net-ssh

I am building a raspberry-pi clients manager, where those clients are connected to a server through SSH reverse tunnels. I am using for this the `Sinatra framework` and the `net-ssh` library. For single commands this is obvious, I used server-side events where I send the commands to a given url. At That action, the command is pushed to a queue, and get executed asynchronously, then the results get pushed to the event-stream connection whenever data is available, here is the pseudo code of the command runner:

```
 require 'net/ssh'
 # start a separate thread avoid blocking the main thread of the server.
 Thread.start do
      sess = Net::SSH.start(HOST, USER, :password => 'pass', :port => 'port')
      # once a command is pushed to the queue on the dedecated sinatra action
      # the command get executed, once the execution ends this will start listening
      # again
    loop{
      sess.exec! (queue.pop()) do|ch, stream, data|
      #this is the server-sent events stream, here the data is pushed to the client 
      #EventSource 
      stream_event_connection << data
      end
    }
 end
```

for single commands this is ok, for example a command like 'ls /root'. But what I need is to open a live terminal(Interective shell), where the user enters commands and gets results like if its on a real ssh terminal.I though migh be opening a pty on the remote Respberry-PI client, and by using the `expect` library, this will be possible.
For requesting a pty their is the `Net::SSH::Connection::Channel#request_pty` method, but I cannot find any example on how to use it. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for can be done like:

```
shell = sess.shell.open(:pty => true)
...
shell.exec! queue.pop ...
```

Hope that helps